# Is there a way to display both the CSS and source-mapped SCSS in Chrome dev tools?

Tags: css, sass, google-chrome-devtools

Currently, I can only see either one of them while viewing the styling of an element in DevTools.
Is there an extension or a setting that would let me see both the generated CSS as well as the source SCSS?
That would be especially useful when the SCSS is using mixins or functions and I would like to verify that the output CSS is correct.

I know I can achieve this by checking/unchecking the "Enable CSS source maps" in the DevTools settings, closing and relaunching DevTools, but that is a cumbersome and time-consuming method.